# Como corrigir as falhas de instalação do react-native para rodar no IOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

Olá,

Seguindo a [documentação do react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) pareceria simples se fosse apenas fazer o que é indicado, só que não é bem assim, é um ledo engano acreditar que todo o processo irá funcionar da maneira que é orientada pelo site, até porque algumas pessoas já possuem algumas das ferramentas pré-instaladas, além também do fato das versões de algumas bibliotecas serem diferentes, então tudo é relativamente diferente para cada usuário.

Durante o decorrer da instalação, descobri que há várias etapas e processos que não foram muito bem esclarecidas, como por exemplo a instalação dos pods, com os cocoapods, fora as várias inconsistências, além de ter que instalar uma série de dependências, ficou bem confuso entender quem eu devo dar prioridade, se é a documentação do site com uso do npm ou a comunicação dos processos em si, que pedem para utilizar o yarn, além dos vários conflitos internos, devido a uma série de elementos pré-instalados que receberem mensagens do tipo warning, de conteúdos depreciados, fora os problemas de uso de porta, tive que pesquisar muito para conseguir rodar alguma coisa neste sentido, e não pareceu ser uma tarefa tão fácil.

Para corrigir alguns dos problemas, que na documentação não fornece, só consegui através do stackoverflow, todavia, também acabei seguindo receitas falhas, pois são **n** variáveis, e riscos a serem considerados, no final eu entendi como fazer tudo de uma forma funcional, isso se fez valer da experiência que tive e das minhas frustrações do que não conseguia, o problema é que depois que você aprende a fazer, é tarde, você já encheu sua máquina de coisas que não precisava, e de configurações que afetaram outras camadas de desenvolvimento, a coisa toda descambou, e agora, eu tenho variáveis de ambiente que ficaram eternizadas com falhas, e eu não tenho ideia de como consertar isso.

Há muitas respostas, porém nenhuma funcionou até agora, estou com um projeto de teste chamando HelloWord que era o esqueleto inicial para eu aprender a instalar o react-native, eu apaguei esse projeto do computador, e agora, toda vez que faço o passo a passo direitinho de uma nova aplicação, não importa como, esse maldito aparece por traz, parece pegadinha, ele vem e fala, "oi, eu ainda existo para estragar seus futuros projetos... kkkk", então deixo aqui aberto para um especialista, já que existem muitos acredito eu, vir aqui e me dizer o que eu tenho que fazer para corrigir isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Aqui tem exemplos](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/509) do mesmo problema.

Comment: Olá ! Amigo, para fazer a instalação do meu ambiente de desenvolvimento para React Native, utilizei a página da Rocketseat, na qual está bem detalhada e documentada, aconselho a você a utiliza-lá. https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/introducao Obs: Em seu caso da uma olhada no arquivo App.js e verifica para onde está apontando o arquivo inicial.

Comment: Então, @LeonardoLeite, o problema não é dentro da minha aplicação, é alguma variável de ambiente que está agindo como se fosse uma assombração que surge do nada, o mobile está instalando dois apps ao mesmo tempo quando executo a simulação...

Comment: Só deixando claro, que não fui eu que o negativei, ok. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda.